# I need to pass a true or false value after checkbox is clicked to the function in input flag using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
 <input class="bx--toggle" id="toggle-view" type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.monthView" ng-change="vm.getRelevantData()" 
    ng-attr-data-modal-target="{{vm.alertForSaveAll ? '#add-save-all-alert-modal': 'undefined'}}">
```

i have following Html my default vm.monthView is true i need to pass true or false with the check box of this type being checked or unchecked....and need to pass same to the function.

Comment: cant understand your requirement

Comment: make a plunker please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you are trying to get the controller to receive true if the checkbox is checked, and false if not.

If you look in angular's documentation for [input[type=checkbox]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) you will see a very simple example that does exactly that.

I am copying the relevant part here.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2"
       ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
```

Comment: i want to use if conditions on my function can i use that by passing true or false in place of yes or no?

Comment: of course, you can decide whatever you want for the value, and that value will be saved in your scope on the relevant ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>

</head>

  <body data-ng-app="role" data-ng-controller="fooController">
   <input class="bx--toggle" id="toggle-view" type="checkbox" ng-model="monthView" ng-change="getRelevantData(monthView)"></select>
  </body>

</head> 

<script>
  var app = angular.module('role', []);

  app.controller('fooController', function($scope){
    $scope.getRelevantData = function(monthView){
    alert(monthView)
    }
  });
</script>
```